# Why server side socket is not receiving messages after reading "\n.\n"

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I have written simple java client/server program and client is trying to sent like below:

```
os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("HELO\n");    
os.writeBytes("MAIL From: person@example.com\n");
os.writeBytes("RCPT To: to@example.com\n");
os.writeBytes("DATA\n");
os.writeBytes("From: person@example.com\n");
os.writeBytes("Subject: testing\n");
os.writeBytes("Hi there\n"); // message body
os.writeBytes("\n.\n");
os.writeBytes("QUIT");
```

But my server side socket is able to read upto "\n." and then it is waiting to read.

Why is it not reading "QUIT" message after "\n.\n"

Server code:

```
  clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
  is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
  os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.
  while (true) {
    line = is.readLine();
    os.println(line);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try `BufferedReader.readLine()` instead of using DataInputStream.  See the doc athttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html as to why you shouldn't use `DataInputStream`

Comment: This won't work with a real mail server. The line terminator in SMTP is defined as `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a "\n" after QUIT, the stream is reading QUIT, but it doesn't cause the `is.readLine()` because theres no "new line" character in the string